# Comment system - Creating post and showing it on the page -1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There are plenty for scripts on web for comment system. But I felt it very confusing. When we want to customize it, it's like as hole.

I want to create my own simple comment box where user can post and comment.

Here is my space to enter post: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/FNcs8/

```
<lable>Add post </lable><br>
<textarea rows="4" name="Addpost" cols="50" placeholder="Add post"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="share"> </input>
```

Now on button click I can store in the database but how to show in downward each when user enters post and click button? using ajax is jquery which ever efficient and easy
I want to show user image near post. Url is coming from table below.

My table from where data is coming is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_record` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(50) default NULL  //url for picture
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Guys i will put this entire system on github which help other also to learn. Needs help!

UPDATE 1:
ajax.php - for database

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query= "select * from user_record where id=1660546353";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


//build html format as you need it..
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<div class="comment">'.$row ['name'].'<img src="'.$row ['picture'].'"/></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what you are expecting from us ?

Comment: You mean a chat application? not sure if this is the same as comment system.

Comment: How you are storing the details in database? If you are using ajax to store the details, then on success you can retrieve the content you needed form the ajax response and append it some div to show it.

Comment: This won't fix anything however it will be an improvement. I suggest you name all your form elements, that way it will be easier to query later. I.e.: `<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Add post" name="comment_box"> </textarea>` as well as your submit button in using an `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` that way you won't get any unwanted/blank entries. Plus `if(empty($_POST['comment_box'])){ die("Enter a comment"); }`

Comment: Also, one very very important thing you must remember. Always be sanitizing user inputs.

Comment: @Shafeeq: I am not much sound with ajax/jquery. so how to use it for this purpose I dont know.
Just tell me how to write jquery and ajax code in back so that content of post store in `db` and become visible in div below text area.

Comment: @PraveenReddy: that's what exactly I want. I can put  div in gui but how to append the post content in div every time that I could not understand! I apologize for my less knowledge!

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks, its good style! I will follow for next!

Comment: Let me give you code 5 mins..

Comment: @HorseSMith: I could not understand. Can you please elaborate. PLease dont mind my english!

Comment: @Karimkhan What HorseSMith meant is to make sure you use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or other form of protection against injection. PDO is much better to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Oh yes that is very important. My code is always prone to injection but here I will take care!

Comment: @Fred -ii- Also against all kinds of other attacks. Letting users post on a site is a pretty big risk, even if maybe not directly against the site itself then perhaps against other users using it. See XSS.

Comment: `how to show in downward` from this do you mean that it should be like   chat box where new mssages are appended below the last one

Comment: @Karimkhan Very good. And if by chance that PDO is not available on your server, do NOT use `MySQL_` but use `MySQLi_` with the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function.

Comment: @HorseSMith I agree with you `100%`

Comment: Hey guys: what would be better here: ajax or jquery?

Comment: @UDB: yes like when we post and comment on FB

Comment: @Karimkhan A mix of both would be a bonus, however Ajax would be the bare minimum.

Comment: @Karimkhan go for jquery.easy to implement.i shared a code with u.have alook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jquery then use this code

HTML

```
<label>Add post </label><br>
<textarea id="message" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Add post"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="share"> </input>
<div id="commentsholder"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').on('click',function(){
 var commentdata=$("message").val();
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                     data:{ 
            comment: commentdata
                },
        url: "ajax.php",
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            //alert(data);
            $("#commentsholder").append(data);
            }
        },'html');
   });
});
</script>
```

In ajax.php

```
//insert comment into database.
//get the user content who are posting it.
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query= "select * from user_record where id=1660546353";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


//build html format as you need it..
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<div class="comment">'.$row ['name'].'<img src="'.$row ['picture'].'"/></div>';
}
?>
```

That's it.. it should work

Comment: Thanks a ton. LEt me implement!

Comment: PLease see the update1 in my question. I added that part. Give error: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cb/karim/ajax.php on line 10

Warning: Illegal string offset 'picture' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cb/karim/ajax.php on line 10
s`

Comment: what is `comment_id` here?

Comment: @Karimkhan you just wrote the query but you did not run the query.. then you should use that info..

Comment: @Karimkhan i have edited your question and connection part have a look.. Please also read this tutorial you will understand it better.. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Your change in the question does not reflect!

Comment: OH sorry again. Approved it!

Comment: great feeling. It shows photo and name below text area. But comment does not appear there!

Comment: @Karimkhan we didn't added comment in the ajax.php, now you should do a bit research on it :) it's soo simple.. think think...

Comment: I could show it. please see for next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582661/comment-system-showing-post-like-facebook-post-section-php-comment-system-2

Comment: @PraveenReddy Bit of a typo. Change `<lable>Add post </lable>` to `<label>Add post </label>` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

better use jquery.what u can do is put ur textarea inside div tag and then u can dynamically change the position of the div.use javascript to change the name of div tag everytime the submit button is pressed.then u can use the following jquery code i found in net best suited for your problem.when u will post the new comment the older post will shift down logically we are swapping their place.

```
$('.div2:parent').each(function () {
$(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('.div1'));
});
```

if u want any clarification pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this approach i hope this will help you:-

put a block (`ul`) which is hidden when there is no comment above your textarea or the textinput in your fiddle.

```
<ul id="comments" style="display:none"></ul>

<lable>Add post </lable><br>
<textarea  id="cmntinput" rows="4" name="Addpost" cols="50" placeholder="Add post"> </textarea>
<input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="share"> </input>
```

now use jquery ajax as on submit/click event

```
$('#submitbtn').click(function(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault();

    input=$('#cmntinput').val();

    var comment={};

    comment.input=input;

    $.ajax({

            url: 'path/to/php',

            data: comment,

            type: 'POST'

            success: function()

            {


                  $('#comments').append('<li id="cmnt">'+input+</li>)

                  //apply some css changes to `li#cmnt or ul#comments`

                  $('li#cmnt').css({listStleType: 'none'}) //example

                  $('#comments')fadeIn()

            }

            })

           })
```

you have to use php to get the userdata who is commenting for example if this a login based 
website like facebook etc then you can create session at login time and can store username on successfull login in `$_SESSION`. And in the php script that will run on ajax call you can write like

```
session_start();
user=$_SESSION['userid'];

//retrieve data on the basis of userid from table where you are storing user info like name email etc

//on the basis of retrieved data insert the `$_POST['input']`(comment) in appropriate table
```

and if you want to show user name, date etc in the new comments appended use the php to  prepare the whole string for you

```
$output="<li id='cmnt'><ul><li id='name'>".$data['name']."<li id='content'>".$_POST['input']."</li></ul></li>


     //$data[] is the array to store user information that you have retrieved about user
```

and echo it and use it as a response on ajax success to append to `ul#comments`

Comment: your answer is awsome but praveen has already guided me from stract. Thanks a lot!

Comment: P.S.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582661/comment-system-showing-post-like-facebook-post-section-php-comment-system-2